# Background size transition effect doesn't work on nth-child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to add nth-child to the codes below to apply different background images to each divs.

Markup **before** trying:

```
<div class="coldiv">
    <div class="hoverimg">
        <!-- Contents 1 --> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="coldiv">
    <div class="hoverimg">
        <!-- Contents 2 --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.coldiv {
    width:33.3%;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
}

.hoverimg { 
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;
    background:url(../img/bg_btn1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:620px 200px;
}
.hoverimg.on {
    background-size:680px 219px;
}
```

I used addClass to add .on class and it works fine.

But when I add nth-child pseudo like

`.coldiv:nth-child(1) .hoverimg { background:url(../img/bg_btn1.jpg) center center no-repeat; }`

and remove background property from `.coldiv { ~ }` then the transition doesn't work.

I've also tried putting id on each divs instead of nth-child but the same thing happens.

Comment: I think the reason you're experiencing issues is because when you use the pseudo nth child there is no transition happening. Instead it is just overriding the the .hoverimg class. Also why are you using addClass when you could just use the .hoverimg:hover css? Look at this and maybe it will help clear things up http://jsfiddle.net/benneb10/6sh6fmcb/.

Comment: @Benneb10 I've found the solution. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found the solution :)

I separated the properties like this and it works fine:

```
background-position:center center;
background-size:620px 200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your style transition works for you

```
.hoverimg { 
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:width 0.4s ease;
    background-size:620px 200px;
     background:url("../img/bg_btn1.jpg") center center no-repeat; 
}
.coldiv:hover .hoverimg {
    background-size:680px 219px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this one, too :)